# I am just learning and I am asked to write a csv file I keep getting an error but I don't know why?

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv

with open('myaddresses.csv','w','newline')as A:
   thewriter = cav.writer(A)
thewriter.writerow({'11 Wall Street, New York, NY, 10005'})
thewriter.writerow({'350 Fifth Avenue, New York, NY, 10118'})
thewriter.writerow({'1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW, Washington DC, 20500'})
thewriter.writerow({'4059 Mt Lee Dr.,Hollywood, CA, 90068'})
thewriter.writerow({'Statue of Liberty, Liberty Island, New York, NY, 10004'})
thewriter.writerow({'1313 Mockingbird Lane, Albany, NY, 12084'})
thewriter.writerow({'0001 Cemetery Lane, Westfield, NJ, 07091'})
thewriter.writerow({'3109 Grant Ave, Philadelphia , Pa, 19114'})
thewriter.writerow({'532 N. 7th Street, Philadelphia, PA, 19123'})
thewriter.writerow({'317 Chestnut Street, Philadelphia, PA, 19106'})
```

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

any help would be appericated

I just need it to print the information I entered.

Comment: `cav` isn't a valid symbol. Please [edit] to show the precise traceback. Why are you wrapping each string in braces? That only costs extra time by converting it into a set of one string.

Comment: Anyway, if each line is an opaque piece of text, why are you using CSV at all here? A better design would break up the data into separate columns (street address, city, state, zip?)

Comment: You should check [the documentation for the `open` built in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and how (by default) the third argument would be `buffering`, which should be an integer (not the string `'newline'`)

Comment: Your file is closed once the `with` statement completes; the calls to `writerow` have  to be in the body of the `with` statement, where the file is still open.

Answer (score 0):

open does not take an argument 'newline' which is a string. It can take a keyword argument `newline =`.
As the documentation says: newline determines how to parse newline characters from the stream. It can be None, '', '\n', '\r', and '\r\n'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how you call the `open()` function.

```py
# This call will result in TypeError
with open('myaddresses.csv','w','newline')as A:
   # do something with file A
```

The argument `'newline'` isn't assigned properly.
If we look at the function definition:

> open(file, mode='r', buffering=- 1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)

As you call the `open()` function with positional arguments only, you are trying to assign the value `'newline'` to `buffering` which only accepts an integer.

The proper way to call `open()` in your case would be to use the keyword argument for `newline`, that is:

```py
with open('myaddresses.csv', 'w', newline="\n") as A:
    # do something with file A
```

The `newline` argument can be only one of the following:

> None, '', '\n', '\r', and '\r\n'.

The default value for the `newline` argument is `None`.